# ld can't find required libs when building opencv with mingw

Tags: opencv, cmake

I am trying to build OpenCV using MinGW Makefiles as generator. At the stage where it c hecks if compilers are working, it fails with following output:

```
BUILDING FOR: 32 BITS, RELEASE
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.1.0
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.1.0
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/g++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/g++.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:45 (message):
  The C++ compiler

    "C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/g++.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: E:/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command:"C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe"
"cmTC_adda8/fast"
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_adda8.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_adda8.dir/build
    mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'E:/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_adda8.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj
    C:\PROGRA~1\MINGW-~1\X86_64~1.0-W\mingw64\bin\G__~1.EXE    -m32    -o CMakeFiles\cmTC_adda8.dir\testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj -c E:\opencv\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCXXCompiler.cxx
    Linking CXX executable cmTC_adda8.exe
    "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles\cmTC_adda8.dir\link.txt --verbose=1
    "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E remove -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_adda8.dir/objects.a
    C:\PROGRA~1\MINGW-~1\X86_64~1.0-W\mingw64\bin\ar.exe cr CMakeFiles\cmTC_adda8.dir/objects.a @CMakeFiles\cmTC_adda8.dir\objects1.rsp
    C:\PROGRA~1\MINGW-~1\X86_64~1.0-W\mingw64\bin\G__~1.EXE -m32     -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles\cmTC_adda8.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -o cmTC_adda8.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libcmTC_adda8.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 @CMakeFiles\cmTC_adda8.dir\linklibs.rsp
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lkernel32
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libuser32.a when searching for -luser32
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libuser32.a when searching for -luser32
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libuser32.a when searching for -luser32
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -luser32
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libgdi32.a when searching for -lgdi32
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libgdi32.a when searching for -lgdi32
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libgdi32.a when searching for -lgdi32
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgdi32
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libwinspool.a when searching for -lwinspool
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libwinspool.a when searching for -lwinspool
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libwinspool.a when searching for -lwinspool
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lwinspool
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libshell32.a when searching for -lshell32
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libshell32.a when searching for -lshell32
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libshell32.a when searching for -lshell32
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lshell32
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libole32.a when searching for -lole32
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libole32.a when searching for -lole32
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libole32.a when searching for -lole32
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lole32
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/liboleaut32.a when searching for -loleaut32
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\liboleaut32.a when searching for -loleaut32
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/liboleaut32.a when searching for -loleaut32
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -loleaut32
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libuuid.a when searching for -luuid
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libuuid.a when searching for -luuid
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libuuid.a when searching for -luuid
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -luuid
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libcomdlg32.a when searching for -lcomdlg32
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libcomdlg32.a when searching for -lcomdlg32
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libcomdlg32.a when searching for -lcomdlg32
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcomdlg32
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libadvapi32.a when searching for -ladvapi32
...many similar errors
   C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/libstdc++.dll.a when searching for -lstdc++
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lstdc++
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmoldname
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmingwex
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
    C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-W/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmsvcrt
    collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\cmTC_adda8.dir\build.make:88: cmTC_adda8.exe]
Error 1
    mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'E:/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:125: cmTC_adda8/fast] Error 2

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:127 (project)
```

And here is how I call CMake to configure my project:

```
cmake -G"$generator" `
      -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="$uconfig" `
      -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="$c_comp" `
      -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="$flags" `
      -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="$cxx_comp" `
      -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="$flags" `
      -DWITH_GSTREAMER=TRUE `
      -DENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF `
      -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF `
      -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF `
      -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../cv_contrib_latest/modules `
      ../cv_latest
```

where `uconfig=RELEASE` , `generator=MinGW Makefiles`, `arch=32` `flags=m32` and `cxx_comp=mingw-w64/bin directory`. It talks about skipping incompatible when linking libraries. Is this a x86-x64 problem? As far as I know, mingw-w64 compiles both of them and I am passing `-m32` flag to compile x86.

Edit: Using `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe` in the same bin directory for compiling gives the same errors.

Edit 2: Error seems to go away when I remove the `-m32` option so indeed this is realted to an x86-x64 mismath. But, the libs I am trying to link are under the directory `MINGW_PATH/mingw4/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib` so I assumed those would bi 32 bit versions of the libraries. Searching the web, the site where I downloaded `mingw-w64` says it supports both x86 and x64. How can I compile for x86 using mingw-w64?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, mingw-w64 compiler was single target. You need to download another distribution from SourceForge, not the default one. I downloaded and set up `i686-8.1.0-release-win32-sjlj-rt_v6-rev0` as my toolchain and now I am able to compile for x86.

Comment: The funny thing is that installing mingw-w64 on an old 32bit Ubuntu (on a 32bit CPU) via the official repositories yields a mingw-w64, that fails (using `-m32` at least) to build any 32bit applications but succeeds in building 64bit ones.